# Validating an Edit Control's text while the user types MFC

Tags: c++, events, mfc, editcontrol

**Question/Problem:** I have an edit control (text box) that the user enters a username into. I am attempting to compare the username entered to the ones listed in my List Control.  If the username given matches, my button's text should change from `Create User` to `Update User`.

*My problem is in finding the correct event/time to compare the strings, without creating an infinite loop.*

**What I have tried:** I have tried using the edit control events `EN_CHANGE` and `EN_UPDATE`.  Both of these events cause stack-overflow exception or an infinite loop.  I thought that one of these events would be called every time something is typed or the backspace was used within my edit control.

In my `EN_CHANGE` / `EN_UPDATE` event, I compare the username strings and set the button's text. With either event, it is called infinite times:

```
void Users::OnEnUpdateLoginName()  //EN_UPDATE Event
{
    bool match = false;

    //Compare the edit control text with each List Control text.
    for(int i = 0; i<m_UserList.GetItemCount(); i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(m_UserList.GetItemText(i,0),m_loginName)==0)
            match = true;
    }

    //If the usernames match, change the button's text to "Update User"
    if(match) 
    {
        CWnd *currentSelection = GetDlgItem(TXTC_LOGIN_NAME);
        currentSelection->SetWindowTextA("Update User");
    }
    else
    {
        CWnd *currentSelection = GetDlgItem(TXTC_LOGIN_NAME);
        currentSelection->SetWindowTextA("Create User");
    }
}
```

[image: example edit control].

If the text in red matches, change the text of the button highlighted in blue.

Should I be using a different event to validate the string in real-time as the user types?

Comment: Assuming _m_loginName_ represents the edit control, how do you update  it each time a character is entered by the user?  I don't see where that happens in your code.  Also, what is TXTC_LOGIN_NAME?  It's used as if its a button.

Comment: I feel dumb, I have been staring at this too long.  TXTC_LOGIN_NAME should be replaced with `IDC_BUTTON1` (the button to create/update user.  I will see how that effects my code now.  I assumed that _m_loginName_ would be updated automatically when the event was called.

Comment: Effectively, each time you wrote to TXTC_LOGIN_NAME you caused another EN_UPDATE event to occur.  Additionally, the member variable _m_loginName_ will not automatically be updated unless you update it through the code.  There are a few ways to accomplish that.

Comment: would `UpdateData(true)` at the start of my event be one way?

Comment: Yes, but, it will also update data for **all** of the dialog controls, not, just _m_loginName_.  That's not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: Thank you @rrirower .  Using `UpdateData(true)` and the correct button name fixed my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code had two issues.  I needed to use `UpdateData`, so that data for all my dialog controls would be current.  I also was updating the wrong variables.  Thanks @rrirower